# Images not displayed using localhost, after pushing code to github

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

[Live Site](https://dank1368.github.io/intro-section-with-dropdown-navigation)
[Repo](https://github.com/DanK1368/intro-section-with-dropdown-navigation)

I just uploaded this project and the live site works fine. But for some reason the images are now gone when viewing it on localhost. It worked fine until I pushed and published the project.
The images folder is inside the public folder.

Also I just realized that when viewing the site on mobile, I seem to be able to scroll beyond the content (right and down). I’m not sure why that is..I also noticed that when viewing the site in the browser and enable touch simulation. Disabling it, it doesn't scroll beyond the content.

Answer (score 0):

you have specified the file location as "./images/client-databiz.svg" for images

which is need to open the folder named images under the current JS file presents.

since during deploying it will build and make your code into static file

refer[image: the project structure]

you need to use "../../public/images/client-databiz.svg" to preview that actually.

I hope it will also work in production.

Comment: Got it, is it then generally better to have the images/assets folder in the src folder rather than the public one?

Comment: actually It does not have any performance impact, but its good practice to have images under assets, since it is common for people to look.

Comment: Okay, thanks. By the way, any idea why the content seems to overflow or I am able to scroll beyond the content on mobile device. I set my overflow to hidden. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: you can try to remove theme you applied, since it somehow override the initial scale property. if you are familiar with CSS you can directly use them in react.